# nested ui-view not being populated

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to get `ui-router` to properly work with nested `ui-view` elements but I'm having trouble getting the nested view to actually render. Here's my code:

app.js

```
'use strict';

var lunchrApp = angular.module('lunchr', ['ui.router', 'lunchrControllers']);

lunchrApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        $stateProvider.
            state('mainPage', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: '/partials/main.jade',
                controller: 'MainPageController'
            })
            .state('users', {
                url: '/users',
                templateUrl: '/partials/users.jade',
                controller: 'UserController'
            })
            .state('users.matching', {
                url: '/matching',
                templateUrl: '/partials/users.matching.jade'
            })
            .state('users.matched', {
                url: '/matched',
                templateUrl: '/partials/users.matched.jade'
            })
            .state('register', {
                url:'/register',
                templateUrl: 'partials/register.jade',
                controller: 'RegisterController'
            });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);
```

Here's `/partials/users.jade` (which gets properly displayed in the `div(ui-view)` in the `body` tag)

```
div(class='container')
    h1 Welcome

    p(ng-repeat='user in users').
        Username: {{user.email}}
        Firstname: {{user.firstname}} 
        Lastname {{user.lastname}}

    a(ui-sref='users.matching', class='btn btn-default') Start matching me!
    a(ui-sref='users.matched', class='btn btn-default') Simulate a match!
    div(ui-view)
```

Here are `partials/users.matching.jade`

```
div
    h1 We're matching you!
```

and `partials/user.matched.jade`

```
div
    h1 You've been matched!
```

I can successfully navigate to `http://localhost:3000/users/matched` but when I do, the html is identical to when I go to `http://localhost:3000/users`.

Why isn't the nested `ui-view` being correctly populated?

Comment: I've run into this issue a few times. I think it's a jade thing. But in your child view, try changing div(ui-view) ---> ui-view... Make it an element, instead of an attribute.

Comment: That worked. I wonder why...

Comment: Yeah i'm not sure, and its only on child views.

Comment: Um...wtf? Why does it work that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

Just put

```
doctype html
```

at the top of the jade file that contains `<div ui-view>`.

If you want more info, there are a number of pretty [easy solutions](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/247).

## More details

The issue basically comes down to the fact that jade is outputting

```
<div ui-view="ui-view">
```

which angular can't understand. So you have to make some changes to the output so it's something angular can consume.

### Option 1

IMHO, the simplest option would be to put

```
doctype html
```

at the top of the jade file that contains `<div ui-view>`. You must do this even if your jade file is contained within another file that already has `doctype html`.

### Option 2

You can write

```
.div(ui-view="")
```

instead of

```
div(ui-view)
```

This forces jade to output `<div ui-view>`.

### Option 3

Angular will be fine if you specify a class named `ui-view` on your `div`:

```
<div class="ui-view">
```

### Option 4

Maybe the hackiest way would be to write the raw HTML like this:

```
<div ui-view>
```

That makes jade output it exactly the way you typed it.